# Change the URL of my angular app using HREF in the same domain

Tags: html, angular, href

Is it possible to change the URL using `href` in `html`? If i'm clicking the `<a href="http://localhost:4200/products.html>Products</a>` from the `index.html` file. The url is changing 1 second and go back to the `http://localhost:4200/`

Even my `src/app/home/home.component.html` have `<a href="http://localhost:4200/products.html>Products</a>` is still going back to the `http://localhost:4200/` when I clicked the link.

I searched a lot about this problem but all suggestion is about the routing. But I want to refresh the browser by clicking. If href is not possible please give me any idea to solve this problem. Please help me about this problem. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using HTML5 mode in the `$location` service, you can link to the page relatively from the root of the app:

```
<a href="/products.html">Products</a>
```

That stops the `$location` service from rewriting the href. More: [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#html-link-rewriting)

Answer (score 0):

where have you placed your products.html file because what i think is that this page is not being served on this location(localhost:4200/products.html). i am assuming that the products page is an angular component if it is then you can simply implement the click event on the  tag and on click you can navigate the user to this route and refresh the app using the following code

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('products').then(() => {
window.location.reload();
})
```

if its not an angular component then you have to conform that this page is being served on the server location from which you are calling it just write the link

> localhost:4200/products.html

on the browser if this page doesnot show then the problem is with the way you are serving this page to server because it means that the page is not found on this path. and you cannot call the html pages that way you are doing in localhost. just right click on the products.html file where ever it is in your computer and click on open with option choose a browzer and open file in the browzer and you will see the url on the search bar of the browzer just copy the url and paste it in href="/paste copied_url here/" and now it should open the products.html file.
Hope this helps. if you have any questions just comment.

Comment: Hi Sir Fahad, the first one is i'm not getting the point :( can you tell me where I will put this code `this.router.navigateByUrl('products').then(() => {
window.location.reload();
})` or atleast idea only. 

the second one is still my browser is going back to `localhost:4200` I put `<a href="/src/products.html"></a>` or even `<a href="/C:/Users/xd/Desktop/angular-practice/first-practice/src/products.html"></a>` 

please let me know Sir if i'm not getting you. Thank you so much!

Comment: your page (products.html) is an angular component or a seperate html page??

Comment: It is in the outside of the app folder, I don't know what is angular component means, i'm sorry. I'm trying my best to understand you. I'm from pure php and html development, i'm so new about this framework. :(( For you to know, the index.html & products.html is in the same path. `/src/` inside of that path not in the `src/app/`

Comment: Sorry i didn't knew that you were new to angular i would have used some simple words. Just do one thing fist use href="http://www.google.com" with http:// and see if this page is openning or not. if it is opening the google.com page then the problem is with the path you are giving inside the href.